Instrumental Variables
i have to run the following  equation using IV method
D= a+bXt+cUt+dUt-1.
Could you please let me know if it is possible to define Ut and Ut-1 as endogenous variables and use Ut-2 as an instrument in STATA. To put it differently, to use for my two endogenous variable the same instrument (Ut Ut-1=Ut-2).
Many thanks

You need at least as many instruments as endogenous variables. If you use IV estimation, with $U_t$ and $U_{t-1}$ as endogenous and $U_{t-2}$ as instrument you are basically `replacing' $U_t$ and $U_{t-1}$ by a linear combination of $U_{t-2}$ giving the regression:
$$
\begin{align*}
D&= a + b X_t+c \alpha U_{t-2} +d \beta U_{t-2} + \varepsilon\\
 &=a + b X_t+(c \alpha+ d \beta) U_{t-2} + \varepsilon
\end{align*}
$$
You can get estimates for $\alpha, \beta$ and $c \alpha + d \beta$, which is not sufficient to estimate $c$ and $d$ separately.
You could try using instruments $U_{t-2}$ and $U_{t-3}$.
